# Cookie based Load Balancing for WebSockets?

Tags: node.js, websocket, scalability, load-balancing

My situation is that we currently write an online application which uses Node.js on server side with WebSocket listener. We have two different parts: one serves pages and uses node.js and express+ejs, another is a completely different app which only includes socket.io library for websockets.
So here we come to this issue of scalability of websockets part.

One solution we've found is to use redis and share sockets information among servers, but due to architecture it will require sharing of loads of other information, which is going to create huge overhead on servers.

After this intro, my question is - is it possible to use cookie based load balancing for websockets? So that lets say every connection from user with cookie server=server1 will always be forwarded to server1 and every connection with cookie server=server2 will be fw to server2 and connection with no such cookie will be fw to least busiest server.

UPDATE: As one 'answer' says -- yes, i know this exists. Just did not remember that name is sticky session. But the question is -- will that work for websockets? Are there any possible complications?

Comment: This is a question I am very interested in, too, only I don't quite see the problem with load-balancing incoming connections from the browsers (it will just hit one of the servers and stick with it), I'm more interested with how do you actually push to those servers from your backend. Like, I have the backend server that does the actual work and then it will push messages to websockets server via a socket - how do I know which one to push to if I have a cluster? My current idea is to just keep the list of all open connections somewhere in the central db, not sure if it's the best way to go.

Comment: @KOHb I do not have any additional backend behind socket servers. So it is much more simple in my case. But from what you say i would try Redis server for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar problem show up in our Node.js production stack. We have two servers using WebSockets which work for normal use cases, but occasionally the load balancer would bounce these connection between the two servers which would cause problems. (We have Session code in place on the backend that should have fixed it, but did not properly handle it.)

We tried enabling Sticky Session on the Barracuda load balancer in front of these servers but found that it would block WebSocket traffic due to how it operated. I have not researched exactly why, as little information is available online, but it appears that this is due to how the balancer strips off the headers for an HTTP request, grabs the cookie, and forwards the request to the correct backend server. Since WebSockets starts off as HTTP but then upgrades, the load balancer did not notice the difference in the connection and would try to do the same HTTP processing. This would cause the WebSocket connection to fail, disconnecting the user.

The following is what we currently have in place which is working very well. We still use the Barracuda load balancers in front of our backend servers, but we do not have Sticky Sessions enabled on the load balancers. On our backend servers, in front of our application server is HAProxy which does properly support WebSockets, and can provide Sticky Sessions in a 'roundabout' way.

---

**Request Flow List**

1. Incoming Client request hits primary Barracuda Load Balancer
2. Load Balancer forwards to either of the active backend servers
3. HAProxy receives the request and checks for the new 'sticky cookie'
4. Based on the cookie, HAProxy forwards to the correct backend application server

---

**Request Flow Diagram**

```
 WebSocket Request  /--> Barracuda 1 -->\   /--> Host 1 -->\   /--> App 1
------------------->                     -->                -->
                    \--> Barracuda 2 -->/   \--> Host 2 -->/   \--> App 1
```

When the arrows come back to one request, that means the request can flow to either point in the flow.

---

**HAProxy Configuration Details**

```
backend app_1
   cookie ha_app_1 insert
   server host1 10.0.0.101:80011 weight 1 maxconn 1024 cookie host_1 check
   server host2 10.0.0.102:80011 weight 1 maxconn 1024 cookie host_2 check
```

In the above configuration:

- `cookie ha_app_1 insert` is the actual cookie name used
- `cookie host_1 check` or `cookie host_2 check` sets the cookie value

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. But unfortunately we still need to use sticky session a lot for socket connection. Do you proxy the pipe or do you redirect it?

Comment: Due to findings in WebSocket protocol we decided to stick with following solution:
- load balance socket connection on handhsake step (it is fine since handshake is just HTTP) with sticky session and not proxy pipe, but redirect it
- In case if state changes - force-reconnect client, where it again will be load balanced to proper server on handshake
- servers r exposed within sub-domain network (smth like s1-socket.example.com, s2-socket.example.com etc)

But we have no implementation in place yet. I will update you once we have it.

Comment: Your first comment: We still need to use sticky sessions as well, and the above answer is how we implemented Sticky Sessions our own way which bypassed the Load Balancer's Sticky Session usage.

Your second comment: This sounds like a scenario which should work for you. It is still quite similar to ours although the hardware load balancer is not in use. We use HAProxy as our only load balancer which provides the needed functionality.

Comment: @AlexKey did you ever try implementing this in test or production? Did my answer fulfill your original question? If so, please accept it or update your question with more detail. Thanks!

Comment: I will update this topic once we have it implemented, until then i will leave it "unanswered". I already voted for your answer if that matters to you, but i will either mark it as valid answer or update topic depending on outcome of this implementation. Everything about this question is so unclear, so i cannot do it just like that. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: That's fully understandable. I wasn't sure where you were in implementation. When you have more info, please post it and we can continue debugging the issue. For us, this scenario is working very well in production. The only issue we currently have is that users/sessions/requests can become "too sticky" and will not properly load balance after a server failover.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I've always found that load balancing socket io is tricky. Your answer is helping point me to the right direction. 2 years have passed, any updates from anyone on this solution?